# Assign Historic Congressional District to Geo Location using R

Tags: shapefile, r, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to assign historic Congressional Districts to firms their headquarters for a research project. I have already converted the firms' headquarters location from an address to a latitude and longitude specification.

UCLA has already produced shape files of historic districts:
https://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/

I tried to download the shape files in r, but the website blocks attempts to download the shape files in r directly. The direct download link of the shape files of the 112th US Congress is, to download in browser:
https://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/shp/districts112.zip

Importing the shape file in r:

```
library (rgdal)
Congress112 <- readOGR("districts112.shp")
```

From the .shp file, I want to assign the:

```
Congress112@data$STATENAME
Congress112@data$DISTRICT
```

To the firms, based on their latitude and longitude (Apple and Amazon for this example):

```
Firm_Name <- c("Apple", "Amazon")
Latitude <- c(37.30661, 47.622318)
Longitude <- c(-122.080628, -122.336649)

FindDistrict <- data.frame(Firm_Name, Latitude, Longitude)
rm(Firm_Name, Latitude, Longitude)
```

Because I have never worked with shapefiles, I do not know how to search (e.g., which function) for how to assign values from a shape file to variables with a certain latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first thing you have to do is to convert your `dataframe` to a "spatial" object (in this case, `sf` object), so you can make use of the spatial function; I noticed a couple difficulties with your data, first, the coordinate reference system, you do not state that of the apple and amazon sites, so I guess it was lon-lat, then reprojected it to that of the districts; second, districts had invalid geometries so I passed `st_make_valid` in order to use them

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

districts = read_sf("districtShapes/districts112.shp") |>
  select(STATENAME, DISTRICT) |>
  st_make_valid() # polyongs had invalid geometries so let's attemp to make the valid

Firm_Name <- c("Apple", "Amazon")
Latitude <- c(37.30661, 47.622318)
Longitude <- c(-122.080628, -122.336649)

FindDistrict <- data.frame(Firm_Name, Latitude, Longitude)

# make sf (spatial) object for use with spatial functions and set a coordinate reference system
FindDistrict = st_as_sf(FindDistrict, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude")) |> st_set_crs(4326)

# check if projections are the same
st_crs(districts) == st_crs(FindDistrict)

# they are not; so reproject one to that of the other
FindDistrict = st_transform(FindDistrict, st_crs(districts))


# a simple spatial join:
st_join(FindDistrict, districts)

# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 3 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -122.3366 ymin: 37.30661 xmax: -122.0806 ymax: 47.62232
# Geodetic CRS:  GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)
# Firm_Name  STATENAME DISTRICT                   geometry
# 1     Apple California       15 POINT (-122.0806 37.30661)
# 2    Amazon Washington        7 POINT (-122.3366 47.62232)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working perfectly!